# yii2 composer autoload

Tags: yii2

Добрый вечер.

Разрабатываю портал на yii2 basic и возникла необходимость загрузить стороннюю библиотеку, поставил её через composer, вроде все ок.

Как теперь вызвать её? Как я только ни пытался, yii её не видит.

Autoload composer'а во входном файле присутствует.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

если автолоаддер загрузил класс, то просто use потом делайте в нужном месте и все.
Проверьте на всякий случай vendor\composer\autoload_real.php на наличие необходимого класса.